# How to populate the `Services` menu in my application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How would I go about populating the `Services` menu in my `Objective C` application?

I want to enable Services which operate on selected Files similar to those which can be invoked in Finder.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to accomplish? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html Or is it something else?

Comment: @macandyp Thanks. It is difficult to find Guides in Xcode5. I had looked for hours through suggestons for "Services"