# How to add Finder/Services menu items to own macOS contextual menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, menu, appkit, finder

When a file is right-clicked in the macOS Finder, a contextual menu like this shows up. It contains items at the bottom from macOS Services. I'm talking about services from third party such as (in this case) iTerm and Find Any File. How would I go about adding such items to a contextual menu in my own macOS app? Is there a documented API to do this?

[image: Finder contextual menu]

I know this can be done, because it's implemented in at least one other application, see for example the following contextual menu in Find Any File:

[image: Find Any File contextual menu]

Comment: Duplicate of [How to populate the `Services` menu in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423251/how-to-populate-the-services-menu-in-my-application).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Why is it not a duplicate?

Comment: That question was about how to add to the Services menu, which is a different task (and something that's not very difficult to do, as it's well documented). At least, that's how I understand the question.

What I'm asking about is how to add extensions provided by other apps to a contextual menu in my app. I know it can be done, because it's done by some other apps, including Find Any File.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: [Using Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000854-SW1)?

Comment: You should be able to copy menu items from the `NSApplication.servicesMenu`, then add them to your own `NSMenu`.

Answer (score -1):

macOS provides [App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/) for products to integrate with the OS. The [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/) lists the different extension points that can be utilised, along with a description of their purpose.

Based on the example you've provided, it may be the Finder Sync extension that you're looking for, as the documentation states for Finder Sync:

> > Badge local OS X folders to let users know the status of items that are remotely synced. **You can also implement contextual menus** to let users directly manage their synced content.

Comment: It seems that the Finder Sync API only lets you add contextual menus in the Finder. What I'm interested in doing is adding such menus to a contextual menu in my own app and I'm not finding any way to do this in the documentation.